# Does Obliteration ever quote from the Book of Mormon?

Tags: brandon-sanderson, the-reckoners

Brandon Sanderson "The Reckoners" series includes an Epic named Obliteration, who is claimed to only speak in quotes from the Bible.

I am curious: Given that Brandon Sanderson is a believing member of the Church of Latter-Day Saints, does Obliteration ever quote from the Book of Mormon, as the Church includes it in the Bible Canon?

Comment: It's an exaggeration to say that Obliteration *only* speaks in Bible quotes. Quite a lot of his speech is completely normal. He does, however, have a habit of peppering his speech with such quotes.

Answer (score 10):

**Not that I can find.**

Obliteration appears in two books, *Firefight* and *Calamity*. I cross-referenced his quotes against the Book of Mormon and various versions of the Christian Bible. None of them seem to appear there.

### *Firefight*

> Behold also the ships,” he whispered, “which though they be so great,
> yet are they turned about with a very small helm.

This is from [James 3:4](https://biblehub.com/kjv/james/3-4.htm).

> “And I saw an angel coming down out of heaven,” he whispered, “having
> the key to the Abyss and holding in his hand a great chain.…”

This is from Revelation 20:1.

> "To whom shall I speak, and give warning, that they may hear?"
> Obliteration said, passionless. "Behold, their ear is uncircumcised,
> and they cannot hearken."

This is from [Jeremiah 6:10.](https://biblehub.com/jeremiah/6-10.htm)

> “And I looked,” Obliteration said, “and beheld a pale horse. On him
> was Death, and Hell followed with him. Power was given unto them to
> kill with sword, and with hunger, and with death.”

This is from [Revelation 6:8.](https://biblehub.com/revelation/6-8.htm)

> “And Abraham took the wood of the burnt offering,” Obliteration
> called, “and laid it upon Isaac his son. He took the fire in his hand,
> and a knife, and they went both of them together.…”

This is from [Genesis 22:6.](https://biblehub.com/genesis/22-6.htm)

> “And the angel of God spake unto me in a dream,” Obliteration
> whispered. “And I said, Here am I"

This is from Genesis 31:11.

### *Calamity*

> ‘For I am come to set a man at variance against his father, and the
> daughter against her mother…’ ”

This is from [Matthew 10:35.](https://biblehub.com/matthew/10-35.htm)

> ‘And there shall be no night there; and they need no candle, neither
> light of the sun; for the Lord God giveth them light.’ ”

This is from [Revelation 22:5.](https://biblehub.com/revelation/22-5.htm)

> "And there are seven kings: five are fallen, and one is, and the other
> is not yet come," he whispered.

This is from [Revelation 17:10.](https://biblehub.com/revelation/17-10.htm)

> “ ‘And the beast that was, and is not, even he is the eighth, and is
> of the seven, and goeth into perdition….’ ”

This is from [Revelation 17:11.](https://biblehub.com/revelation/17-11.htm)

> “I will take you, and it, to the palace above,” he said. “The new
> Jerusalem. Detonate the bomb with this.”

A reference to [Revelation 21:2.](https://biblehub.com/revelation/21-2.htm)

> “ ‘You shall eat the fruit of the labor of your hands; you shall be
> blessed, and it shall be well with you.’

This is from [Psalm 128:2.](https://biblehub.com/psalms/128-2.htm)

> “ ‘And he placed at the east of the garden of Eden Cherubims, and a
> flaming sword which turned every way, to keep the way of the tree of
> life.’ ”

This is from [Genesis 3:24](https://biblehub.com/genesis/3-24.htm).

All of Obliteration's Biblical quotes seem to be from parts of the Bible viewed as canonical by Catholic and Protestant denominations, not from the Book of Mormon.

Comment: In Firefight I think there are also quotations from Revelation 20:1 and Genesis 31:11. But indeed nothing from The Book of Mormon.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez - Could you edit them in?

Comment: I've put them in, maybe you want to put links to your preferred online Bible

Comment: and BTW I concur on the quotes from *Calamity*